# Yii2 AssetBundle Добавить svg,eot,ttf,woff,woff2

Tags: yii2

Как можно добавить, в свой класс наследуемый от AssetBundle, ссылку на svg,eot,ttf,woff,woff2 файлы ? Читал документы но не понял.

Comment: а зачем в ассет добавлять ссылки на шрифты если пути к шрифтам пишут в CSS файлах?

Comment: Для удобства при использовании, там очень редко ошибка выходит что не грузятся иконки. Прям 1 раз из 1000.

Comment: кэшироватьть надо ..... .. и в чём удобство? только ошибку пофиксить ? ну такое себе удобство

Comment: И вообще непонятно почему такая уверенность что эта ошибка не будет тогда возникать....